# Oracle SQL - Looking to execute Outer query for each row returned by inner query

Tags: sql, loops, oracle11g

This is my first ever question :

Below is what I am trying to execute :

---

```
update SRM_SR_AuditLog
   set MODIFIED_DATE = '1426816800'
     , USER_X = 'Vaibhav via DB'
 where REQUEST_ID in (
    select max(REQUEST_ID) from SRM_SR_AuditLog
     where ORIGINAL_REQUEST_ID = (
        select SYSREQUESTID from SRM_Request
         where REQUEST_NUMBER in (
           'ASREQ0000136770', 'ASREQ0000137758', 'ASREQ0000138174',                       
           'ASREQ0000138175', 'ASREQ0000138176', 'ASREQ0000138177',
           'ASREQ0000138178', 'ASREQ0000138180', 'ASREQ0000138181', 
           'ASREQ0000138238', 'ASREQ0000138319', 'ASREQ0000138349', 
           'ASREQ0000139486', 'ASREQ0000140292', 'ASREQ0000140295', 
           'ASREQ0000140299', 'ASREQ0000140334', 'ASREQ0000140403', 
           'ASREQ0000140637', 'ASREQ0000140692' )
    )
);
```

---

I know below wouldnt work :

```
ORIGINAL_REQUEST_ID = (
  select SYSREQUESTID from SRM_Request where REQUEST_NUMBER in
```

Because query (`select SYSREQUESTID from SRM_Request** where REQUEST_NUMBER = "XYZ"`) will return more one records but for each of that record in SRM_Request there are more than one records in table "SRM_SR_AuditLog". I want the latest/biggest request id reference from "SRM_ST_Audit" table for each of the SYSREQUESTID returned by above query.

Hope this makes sense.

I want to execute outer query for each value returned by inner query.
How can I proceed on this please ?

Thanks heaps
Vab

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, then I think what you want is this:

```
update SRM_SR_AuditLog set
MODIFIED_DATE = '1426816800',
USER_X = 'Vaibhav via DB' where
REQUEST_ID in
(
  select max(REQUEST_ID) from SRM_SR_AuditLog where
  ORIGINAL_REQUEST_ID IN
  (
    select SYSREQUESTID from SRM_Request where REQUEST_NUMBER in
    (
    'ASREQ0000136770', 'ASREQ0000137758', 'ASREQ0000138174', 'ASREQ0000138175', 'ASREQ0000138176', 'ASREQ0000138177', 'ASREQ0000138178', 'ASREQ0000138180', 'ASREQ0000138181', 'ASREQ0000138238', 'ASREQ0000138319', 'ASREQ0000138349', 'ASREQ0000139486', 'ASREQ0000140292', 'ASREQ0000140295', 'ASREQ0000140299', 'ASREQ0000140334', 'ASREQ0000140403', 'ASREQ0000140637', 'ASREQ0000140692'
    )
  )
  group by ORIGINAL_REQUEST_ID
)
```

This will find all request IDs in `SRM_Request` for the given request numbers; find all rows in `SRM_SR_AuditLog` whose original request ID is in those request IDs; find the maximum region ID for each unique original request ID; and update the rows with those request IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply Dave.

SRM_Request has one to many mapping with SRM_SR_AuditLog table.

updating to "IN" will scan all records and find just one record with max(REQUEST_ID).

select SYSREQUESTID from SRM_Request where REQUEST_NUMBER in
(
'ASREQ0000136770', 'ASREQ0000137758', 'ASREQ0000138174', 'ASREQ0000138175', 'ASREQ0000138176', 'ASREQ0000138177', 'ASREQ0000138178', 'ASREQ0000138180', 'ASREQ0000138181', 'ASREQ0000138238', 'ASREQ0000138319', 'ASREQ0000138349', 'ASREQ0000139486', 'ASREQ0000140292', 'ASREQ0000140295', 'ASREQ0000140299', 'ASREQ0000140334', 'ASREQ0000140403', 'ASREQ0000140637', 'ASREQ0000140692'
  )

This will return 20 references
for each of these 20 references - I want 20 references from SRM_SR_AuditLog via max(REQUEST_ID).

"select max(REQUEST_ID) from SRM_SR_AuditLog where "

"IN" or "=" wouldnt help.